# Copy files between servers on different physical locations and domains

Tags: powershell, copy

First post here, and bringing a (maybe) big challenge for you. I'm trying to reach my objective for 2 days, without luck.

I need to copy a huge list of files ("only" something about 900k files, about 3tb of data) from a server to another. The problem is: these servers aren't on same network/domain, and aren't on same place. In fact, they are on different cities, and each one have your own domain.

We can access each server with a terminal server connection (to get rid of IP, we use NO-IP services), but we can't copy so many files using this method. We know we can use FTP and/or VPN, but because the huge size of data, it simply don't work (connections lost, timeouts, and so on...).

So, starting from [here](https://techexpert.tips/powershell/powershell-copy-files-remote-computers/), I found Powershell as a candidate to solve the problem, using `New-PSSession` and/or `New-PSDrive`. In fact, powershell even ask for user/password, but I couldn't be able to connect one server to another. To get worse, I'm a noob with Powershell.

Well, the first requisite I saw is to add the servers to a trust list, and check if WinRM is working on both. I did it with `winrm quickconfig` and `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value 'no-ip.servername.here'`. Both commands on both servers returns good.

Then, tried to connect server A with B. On server A I used `$server_b = New-PSSession -computername no-ip.servername.here -credential domain_b\administrador`. At this ponit, server A asks for username and password. I type, but powershell returns a lot of errors about authentication, kerberos, wrong user/password, and so many others. I can't offer a screenshot, because our servers uses Brazilian Portuguese systems.

Reading more about `New-PSSession`, I just tried a lot of options, like authentication, transport, connectionuri, and others, without success...

So, what you can suggest to me?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Why can't you mount both locations within Windows and just transfer copy the files? By attempting to script it you will have to continuously authenticate both sessions instead of the single authentication session mounting the network location would require.  3 TB isn't a great deal of data, I transfer that amount of data, daily between my servers.

Comment: One server don't have a super_mega internet connection. 3Tb is a problem. Autentications isn't a problem, as we will connect using the method often, but I will search a way to get autentication without have to type user/pass every time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I did it! WOW!

Let's go:

1. Make sure WinRM service is up and running on both computers: `get-service winrm`. If not, start it: `start-service winrm`
2. Make sure port 5985 is open. Do your own with your modem/router
3. Make sure your client NO-IP address is trusted on server: `get-item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts`. If not, add it: `set-item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts -value 'client_no-ip_address' -force`
4. Make sure your server is trusted by your client like above, but use your **server** NO-IP address
5. On client, disable some security check: `$option = new-pssessionoption -skipcacheck -skipcncheck`
6. Connect to your server: `$my_server = new-pssession -computername server_no-ip_address -credential domain\user -sessionoption $option`

Here you go!