# Powershell New-PSDrive from remote computer

Tags: powershell, remote, robocopy, copy

I'm here again with one more question.

As stated [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1725208/copy-files-between-servers-on-different-physical-locations-and-domains), I sucessfully connected two servers to copy a lot of files. But the copy won't worked at all. It returns a lot of errors on files and folders wich already exist on destination server.

What I did was create a PSSession as described on the given link above. I can sucessfully see the files from source server with `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem -Path "d:\" } -Session $source_server`. Then, started the copy with:

```
copy-item -path "d:\folder_on_source_server\*" -destination "d:\folder_on_destination_server" -FromSession $source_server -recurse -exclude "*dfsrprivate*",".dropbox.cache"
```

Source and destination folder names are the same. In fact, both servers have same folder structure. But, as stated, I received a lot of errors on files and folders already present on destination. And I mean A LOT. Only new files was copied, updated files don't. I know -force option will work, but it will copy everything again.

My aim now is to copy all new **AND** updated files from source, but copy-item don't have such function. So, I tried use robocopy. The problem is I don't know how to tell robocopy to use the remote server folder as source. I know robocopy can use UNC paths, but I don't have ideas to parse the remote UNC path to it. Something like `robocopy remote_source_folder local_destination_folder /mir` and setting up exclusions.

I tried to create a PSDrive, but is created on source server only. Local robocopy can't see it: Invoke-Command -session $vms -ScriptBlock { New-PSDrive -name "S" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\remote_server_ip\d$" }. If I remove -session, the drive is created somewhere wich I don't know .

I tried also some other commands like net use, created a variable with get-childitem on source, and others, all with and without invoke-command and with and without -session, but none worked.

So, can you help me to get these files? I think is a simple thing, but i'm not seeing it. Also, if you can point me a way to start the pssession without have to type user and password, will be nice.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: You can't expect `copy-item` to work, if the source and destination paths are identical, the directory structure can be the same. *Is the volume drive letter to both locations actually identical?*  Why don't you just run `New-PSDrive` once for the source and once for the destination then use copy-item between the two locations?  Which was my original suggestion, more or less, but I suggested just mounting the network locations within File Explorer.

Comment: Hello Ramhound! Well, they have same names, paths and structure, but aren't the same. But isn't a problem, as I used "-FromSession $source_server" on the command. copy-item understood I'm getting the files from the remote pssession!

Comment: Why are you using the same drive letter?  `\remote_server_ip\d$` maps the remote server to `D:\` and if both servers have identical folder structure your first command which you claim generates errors indicating the file already exists is explained by the fact you are mapping both servers to the same drive letter.  *In other words the files *actually do exist.

Comment: Thanks Ramhound. Was a mispelling fault on original post: the source uses UNC, not a drive letter. Sorry.

Comment: So [edit] your question to be correct.  `d$` is basically UNC notation for `D:\`

Comment: Thanks again, Ramhound, but isn't needed. I made some tests, and the `-fromsession` option works as spected. See: on remote server I created a test file on root of physical d: drive. This file don't exist on local d:. I ran the copy command from local server using d:, and the test file was copied.

Comment: Did other test: `invoke-command -scriptblock {get-childitem -path "\\remote_server_ip\d$"} -session $remote_server` returns the root of remote D:. Then `$file_list = invoke-command -scriptblock {get-childitem -path "\\remote_server_ip\d$"} -session $remote_server`. $file_list returns the same as first command. Then `robocopy "$file_list" "local_server_folder" /mir /r:0 /w:0` inside or not 'invoke-command' returns an error saying can't find file 'c:\windows\windows\system32\_the_first_file_on_$file_list'. I just need a way to convert 'remote_server_ip' to something robocopy can handle.