# Robocopy using a NO-IP address

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I think I was unluck to explain what I need on my 2 first posts. Let's try one more time...

Just need to sync a folder from a computer in a different city. But I don't know how to tell robocopy to use a NO-IP address of machine!

`robocopy "no-ip_address\d$\source_folder" "d:\localfolder" /mir /r:0 /w:0`

1. Need to be NO-IP address because the server is located in another city. But if you have suggestions, I'll analyse.
2. **NEED** to be robocopy, because we already did a full copy with copy-item in Powershell, so we don't want to copy about 3,5Tb of data again and again, and lefting deleted files and folders on destination.
3. Both computers can connect themselves using New-PSSession. We got the full copy using this way, in fact.

Tried a lot of things these days without lucky. References [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1725208/copy-files-between-servers-on-different-physical-locations-and-domains) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1725383/powershell-new-psdrive-from-remote-computer).

PS.: I had a half-success for reference 2. But robocopy deal the remote source path as a local path, so didn't work as spected.

Hope I get understood now... lol...

Comment: Do you mean a domain name? (Even then, it doesn't seem like it has anything to do with the server being in another city.) What UNC path were you using with Copy-Item? Have you tried just using _exactly the same_ UNC path with Robocopy as well?

Comment: Thanks @user1686 , but no, is a NO-IP address, a service to get something like myserver.no-ip.com using your internet IP. About copy-item, I didn't used UNC, was the real path on remote computer, the difference is the `-fromsession` option. Something like this: `copy-item -path "d:\folder_on_source_server\*" -destination "d:\folder_on_destination_server" -FromSession $source_server -recurse`. Note I used same drive letter, but it works because `-fromsession`. You need a PSSession opened to this work.

Comment: Set the source folder as a share on the remote system. The share name can be different than the actual path. The shared folder's root will be the remote host name, not the actual HDD path. The folder would then be browse-able via explorer using `\\foo.remotecomputer.bar\NameOfShare`. Sort this first, then try robocopy.

Comment: I already tried using `robocopy "\\no-ip_address\shared_folder" "d:\localfolder" /mir /r:0 /w:0`, but it says the path don't exists. Note: remote computer isn't on same network/place/domain as local computer!

Comment: **Workaround**: connect your client to remote computer using Remote Desktop Access, turning on an option to show the local computer drives on remote session. Then, on remote session: `robocopy "source_folder" "\\tsclient\local_folder"`